# Ubuntu went black screen during regular update but can still ssh in, how to tell if it's safe to reboot?

Tags: updates, ssh

I can access the machine via ssh.

Running htop etc I can see stuff I guess but not sure how to tell an "updates being applied" is still running.

Is there a way to tell?

Comment: Try `sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop^` to restore GUI, in case it was gone.

Comment: If that fails to run, due to unable to obtain lockfile, then updates are still running

Comment: Just happened to me too when the Nvidia driver updated to 535.86.05 -- could use a virtual term, used top, didn't see any updates running,but firefox was 100%.  Couldn't even sudo kill -9 to stop it!  Just rebooted and all was OK.

Comment: try type "ps -ef --sort=start_time | grep -i update"

Comment: @ubfan1 yep seems fine now after reboot. Maybe a few weeks same thing happened to me during an upgrade and it was *not* so good so I'm a bit paranoid now.